# A crime has been committed! ...so here is a riddle

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, rhyme

> Here is a riddle about a crime, forgive me as not all will rhyme,
>
> Am I trespassing? I am not! ...yet where I am matters a lot,
>
> I hurt someone? That is not true!  I'm peaceful, kind and gentle too.
>
> Stealing? Never! Not my game!  Doing no harm is my sole aim!
>
> "Protester", "Vandal" I am not!  I don't deserve what I got!
>
> My profession is not bold, I've always done as I was told.
>
> Nothing petty I have done, nor have I possessed a gun.
>
> Not lewd or rude my actions be, No slight was ever made by me.
>
> And just because I never lie, This line won't rhyme at all!

Where am I and of what crime do I speak?

Hint:

> The crime is very much a real crime!

Bigger Hint:

> All of the answers so far have made an incorrect assumption about the crime.

Comment: SUICIDE by a gun standing on a wall of own house! :p

Comment: drunk driving ?

Comment: Not a bold profession? Probably a refree for olympic? He carries a gun and probably he was high on drugs on the race day.

Comment: This reminds me of "whitemailing" from the genius of Sir Terry Pratchett.

Comment: And it reminds me of a movie "Touching the void" where a mountaineer leaves his companion for dead on Everest trek.

Comment: Does the profession matter?  This seems like it's verging on too broad.

Comment: Something about testify in court or another formal proceeding?

Comment: @danRussel The most important lines are about where I am being important and not deserving what I got.

Comment: @paparazzi nope, not quite.

Comment: @BrentHackers is this crime still illegal nowadays?

Comment: Crime-a? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimea

Comment: @thegreatduck Excellent question! Yes it is! Very!

Comment: @BrentHackers is it considered illegal in most modern countries or is it something more obscure? Because technically certain religions are illegal if you're in the wrong 3rd world country.

Comment: @thegreatduck it's pretty darned illegal pretty much everywhere that I'm aware of, at least in most first world countries, and probably every country in the UN I'd think.  Immoral too.

Comment: Must be politics, then...

Comment: Would this crime have even been possible say, two centuries ago? I'm thinking cyber-crime.

Comment: @xenocacia42 It's not exclusively modern or anything, no.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Is the location you're in:

> Prison? (**EDIT**: Or anywhere, actually...)

Is the crime:

> False imprisonment?

You're not trespassing, because:

> You're allowed to be there, you just don't want to be.

Where you are matters a lot, because:

> It's the basis of the crime.

You don't deserve what you got, because:

> Your other statements suggest that you haven't done anything wrong!

The assumption other answers made (bigger hint) is:

> That you are the perpetrator, rather than the victim of the crime.

Comment: Holy crap this makes way too much sense to not be the right answer. Kudos to you!

Comment: Well done dood! Have a big shiny +1

Comment: Thanks for creating something that got me to stop just lurking on Puzzling SE!

Comment: Hey, you shouldn't just be lurking if you can solve this.  Well done and welcome to puzzling.

Comment: Now that's what we call Lateral Thinking, awesome puzzle, awesome answer. +1 for both.

Comment: @BrentHackers Not to be too nit-picky, but this is not actually a crime.  False imprisonment involves holding someone without legal justification. Being arrested and convicted for an actual crime which you didn't commit isn't illegal, it's unjust. So no crime has been committed, just a miscarriage of justice.

Comment: @danrussel I never actually said that the crime was committed by me. :)

Comment: @BrentHackers Obviously, but my point is that if you're going for "false imprisonment" as a crime, it's not.  A person being convicted of a crime he/she didn't commit is not a crime itself.  So the "where" part can still be prison, but we still have no idea who actually committed the real crime or what it was.

Comment: @weshall Thanks very much.  It is much better now thanks to input from some of the earlier answerers.

Comment: @DanRussell Borrowing a definition from google "False imprisonment is the unlawful restraint of a person against her will by someone without legal authority or justification." It is a crime to falsely imprison someone.  The crime was committed by whomever imprisoned me.

Comment: @BrentHackers Exactly: "... *without legal authority or justification* ." So you will almost never see a case of false imprisonment *in a prison*. Read more [here](http://injury.findlaw.com/torts-and-personal-injuries/false-imprisonment.html) or [here](http://legaldictionary.net/false-imprisonment/).  I think it's a clever puzzle idea, but should really be tidied up.  If you're in a prison, you've almost certainly been *convicted* of a crime and thus aren't falsely imprisoned. Conversely, if you're falsely imprisoned, you're almost certainly *not* in a prison.

Comment: I could be wrong but I based the riddle on the understanding that people can be convicted of a crime that they did not commit and sent to a prison.  This is illegal and unjustified even if sanctioned by the proper authorities.

Comment: @BrentHackers That's exactly what I was trying to convey: it's the opposite of illegal/criminal, it's very very legal because it's been through the legal system. What's legal/criminal is very different from what's right/moral.

Comment: @DanRussell I agree, but from a different angle and so come to an alternate conclusion. False imprisonment is a crime. It certainly *could* happen in a prison, but not exclusively or perhaps even commonly. This adds ambiguity. For the purposes of this puzzle, I think that having to state where the puzzle's protagonist is located shouldn't be necessary, but the clue that the location "matters a lot" is still valid. I made a jump to assume that "false imprisonment" = "prison" in my answer, which could lead to an assumption of context which simply isn't present in the riddle itself.

Comment: It seems to me that if we allow the speaker to be the victim rather than the perpetrator, then *all* the information in the puzzle is this: (1) I am the victim of a crime. (2) My location matters a lot. This is not enough to pin the crime down to the one specified here, even if we discount Dan's objection. Perhaps the crime is bank robbery and you are a bank teller who got beaten up during the robbery. Perhaps the crime is grievous bodily harm and you are in hospital. Perhaps the crime is hijacking and you are in a cockpit.

Comment: @BrentHackers If you are falsely convicted of a crime, then who has actually done anything illegal? Sure, the actual perpetrator of the crime did something, but the judge didn't break the law, nor did the lawyers break the law. It's not criminal nor is it immoral. If anything, false accusation due to misinterpretation of the evidence is just... unfortunate.

Comment: @BrentHackers In contrast, I could argue that you are the guard in an illegal prison, but that would make little sense.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I agree, and that's why I bothered bringing this up. I honestly don't think the puzzle holds together in its current form. And since the puzzle doesn't specify that the person in question has to be *either* victim or perp, there are still tons of valid possibilities that fit all clues, like a person whose shirt was burned when an arsonist torched a dry cleaner's shop.

Comment: @DanRussell - [post 1/2] There are intentional and non-intentional false imprisonments. As with most legal matters the motive & intent are often the key factors in determining criminality. **EXAMPLE #1**: A prosecution witness erroneously testifies in good faith leading to a guilty conviction. This is false imprisonment but it is not criminal.

Comment: @DanRussell - [post 2/2] **EXAMPLE #2**: Someone in the judicial process [a] intentionally lied (including witness perjury, false police reports or planted evidence), [b] suppressed exculpatory evidence, or [c] intentionally failed to defend their client. All of these would create victims who were "legally" processed yet criminally incarcerated wrongly.

Answer (score 5):

Are you

> a pacifist deserter from the army?

*Am I trespassing? I am not! ...yet where I am matters a lot,*

> Where you are (in the army) is highly relevant to your situation. In normal life, refusing to obey orders or kill people would not have been considered a crime.

*I hurt someone? That is not true! I'm peaceful, kind and gentle too.*

*Stealing? Never! Not my game! Doing no harm is my sole aim!*

> Being gentle and doing no harm, and especially being *peace*ful, is a problem when you're in the army fighting a war. Not hurting people could literally be considered a crime.

*"Protester", "Vandal" I am not! I don't deserve what I got!*

> I would agree that a kind and gentle person who was conscripted into the army but refused to hurt people wouldn't deserve whatever fate such criminals tend to get.

Comment: Love it!  Not the answer but not a bad fit an really good explanations.  +1

Comment: @BrentHackers If this isn't the answer, maybe you should add some extra clues to the riddle to prevent it from being "too broad"? :-)

Comment: How's that look to you?

Comment: @BrentHackers Well, that certainly invalidates this answer :-) Gotta think some more then. Are we looking for a real crime, or could it all be something metaphorical? (Feel free to not answer this.)

Comment: Its a very real crime.  I'll add that as a hint I think! +1

Answer (score 4):

How about

> North Korea

Because

> If you committed a crime you don't have the right to free speech

Comment: ROFL +1 I actually thought of this as a sarcastic response to myself!  (Great minds and so on, eh?)  Not the answer though.

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> Standing in court

and have you just committed

> Perjury, the crime of lying under oath

Why?

> Saying "I've always done as I was told." and "Nothing petty I have done" alongside "And just because I never lie" are all lies, unless you have had a 100% clean sheet since you where born.

Comment: Nope.  I never lie in rhyme!  I haven't told a lie...  But I haven't told you everything obviously:) +1

Answer (score 3):

> Are you number 0?

Am I trespassing? I am not! ...yet where I am matters a lot,

> meaning that it's between negative and positive reals. Second half: 01 as opposed to 10, etc.

I hurt someone? That is not true! I'm peaceful, kind and gentle too.

> since it is the identity in addition

Stealing? Never! Not my game! Doing no harm is my sole aim!

> ditto

My profession is not bold, I've always done as I was told.

> as opposed to writing the name of vectors in boldface?

And just because I never lie, This line won't rhyme at all!

> potentially a joke since -0 and +0 is the same (- being 'False' and + 'True' ?)

Comment: No THAT is lateral... +1

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> A Spy in another country?

"Protester", "Vandal" I am not! I don't deserve what I got!

And just because I never lie, This line won't rhyme at all!

> If the lines rhymed, it would have revealed the truth as it might have ended with **"Spy"**

Comment: The rhymes were within each line ("not" & "got", "Game" & "Aim", etc.) so the word would have rhymed with "Lie" not "Got".  Anyhow, it's not hidden in the words like that.

Comment: @BrentHackers - Updated my answer :D Though, I know its not an answer.

Comment: No closer I'm afraid. +1 for sticking to your guns though.

Comment: Haha and I guess it meets the rhymes conditions as well. Though, will wait for the actual answer. A hint will help though.

Comment: I think the correct answer fits far better than anything I've been able to think of but it's not for me to judge.  If I've done this right you'll be kicking yourself for not thinking laterally enough when you do see the answer.  :)  I'll post a hint as soon as I can think of one that doesn't feel like a dead giveaway.

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Jaywalking?

Here is a riddle about a crime, forgive me as not all will rhyme,

> I'm not sure if it's a crime, but it is illegal in many places to jaywalk.

Am I trespassing? I am not! ...yet where I am matters a lot,

> You're crossing the street in the wrong place, and that is your infraction.

I hurt someone? That is not true! I'm peaceful, kind and gentle too.

Stealing? Never! Not my game! Doing no harm is my sole aim!

"Protester", "Vandal" I am not! I don't deserve what I got!

> This illegal activity is not a very violent one, nor does it involve stealing.

Comment: I'm not, but I see where you're coming from.  I'll update with another line. +1

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> An environmental protester?  Like the Greenpeace folks trying to save the whales on the open seas?

Or maybe

> a religious missionary somewhere that is illegal?  Non-violent, not stealing, trying to save souls?

Comment: I specifically mention not being a protestor.  Your other idea is pretty good  +1but not the answer.  I'll add another hint.

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> A double agent?

Am I trespassing? I am not! ...yet where I am matters a lot,

I hurt someone? That is not true! I'm peaceful, kind and gentle too.

> Technically, he belongs to both the sides. He does it for financial benefit with no intention of physically hurting someone.

Stealing? Never! Not my game! Doing no harm is my sole aim!

"Protester", "Vandal" I am not! I don't deserve what I got!

> He doesn't steal information. He just betrays one side.

my profession is not bold, I've always done as I was told.

Nothing petty I have done, more have I possessed a gun.

> As I said, there is nothing wrong for him to do something to be rich.

Comment: This won't hold based on "``Doing no harm is my sole aim!``" A double agent intends to betray one of their employers and thereby directly or indirectly damage their work (which is what the other side pays them to do). And intentional or not, such betrayals often lead to people dying.

Answer (score 2):

Where am I and of what crime do I speak?

> You're in your car, and the crime is a DUI (Driving Under the Influence).

Here is a riddle about a crime, forgive me as not all will rhyme,

Am I trespassing? I am not! ...yet where I am matters a lot,

> Being intoxicated isn't a crime, but it is in this case because of where you are (in your car).

I hurt someone? That is not true! I'm peaceful, kind and gentle too.

> You didn't hurt anyone.

Stealing? Never! Not my game!

> You didn't have to steal to commit this crime.

Doing no harm is my sole aim!

> Though drunk, you're really trying to drive well enough not to cause harm.

"Protester", "Vandal" I am not! I don't deserve what I got!

> You didn't protest or vandalize, and perhaps you think you're just a bit over the limit.

my profession is not bold, I've always done as I was told.

> Could be lots of things.

Nothing petty I have done, more have I possessed a gun.

> It's not petty to drink and drive!

And just because I never lie, This line won't rhyme at all!

> Or maybe you think it does, since you're drunk.

Comment: My reasoning for _never lie_ part was 'Breath Analyzer'

Comment: If nothing else this made me chuckle and it wasn't a bad fit +1

Answer (score 2):

Are you:

> Jaywalking?

```
Here is a riddle about a crime, forgive me as not all will rhyme,
Am I trespassing? I am not! ...yet where I am matters a lot,
```

> You're in the middle of the road which is illegal.

```
I hurt someone? That is not true! I'm peaceful, kind and gentle too.
```

> Jaywalking is merely standing in the middle of the road. It doesn't hurt anyone unless you get hit by a car.

```
Stealing? Never! Not my game! Doing no harm is my sole aim!
```

> Or do you intend to hurt yourself? Just kidding. You're probably just not thinking it through.

```
"Protester", "Vandal" I am not! I don't deserve what I got!
```

> A jaywalker in the wrong location could be interpreted as a protestor blocking the road.

```
My profession is not bold, I've always done as I was told.
```

> Simply reasserting that he's not on strike. He is merely walking illegally.

```
Nothing petty I have done, nor have I possessed a gun.
```

> It is certainly not a petty crime to put one's life in danger!

```
Not lewd or rude my actions be, No slight was ever made by me.
```

> I disagree and think standing in the road is rude, but that's beside the point. It isn't directly and deliberately rude towards any individual.

```
And just because I never lie, This line won't rhyme at all!
```

> referring to the first statement which says this whole riddle won't rhyme. Probably just a red herring.

Comment: This answer was [already given](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/44693/4421) by ffao 2 hours ago...

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain my answer is not the same as their's. I have much more extensive explanations. Also, many people give the same answer all the time. Why should this matter? I thought of an answer. I shouldn't have to read 11 answers just to be sure.

Comment: Actually, nothing is served by posting duplicate answers.  You *should* in fact be reading the other answers before posting your own (or it will probably just get deleted).  Note also that the OP has already indicated that ffao's answer is not correct, so whether you're providing more detail is kind of moot; you're not helping by providing a known-to-be-incorrect answer.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain the other answer you point out is barely even worthy of being an answer on this site. It makes no attempt to explain why it chose that answer. Also, this site is not about "right or wrong" answers. We are merely guessing at solving the riddles. I've seen people post obviously wrong answers that are quite clever in the way they explain themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> Public Nudity?

Am I trespassing? I am not! ...yet where I am matters a lot,

> You're not trespassing, so you're likely in a public place

I hurt someone? That is not true! I'm peaceful, kind and gentle too.

> Not sure about this, perhaps it simply excludes violent crimes as possibilities

Stealing? Never! Not my game! Doing no harm is my sole aim!

> Being naked technically does not hurt anybody

"Protester", "Vandal" I am not! I don't deserve what I got!

> Being naked in public may be thought to be protesting something, and being naked is natural so it seems like being arrested for it is undeserved

my profession is not bold, I've always done as I was told.

> Not sure about this: maybe someone dared you to go in public naked for money, as you don't have a great job and need the extra cash?

Nothing petty I have done, more have I possessed a gun.

> It's a big deal to go outside naked. The gun could either reference that you cannot carry a firearm if you're naked, or people can literally see your 'weapon'

And just because I never lie, This line won't rhyme at all!

Comment: I like it +1 and I hadn't thought of that one! but its not that.  I'll add another line.